# Is it possible to use wkhtmltopdf on AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

There are some Node Js github repos for this. I am a newbie to Node, therefore I used python to try this out.

**Problem**

I am getting permission denied error on lambda. Below is my code as well as error with the code.

**Error**

```
{
      "errorMessage": "[Errno 13] Permission denied",
      "errorType": "PermissionError",
      "stackTrace": [
        [
          "/var/task/htmlToPdf.py",
          50,
          "handler",
          "c=pdfkit.from_string(document,False,configuration=config )"
        ],
        [
          "/var/task/pdfkit/api.py",
          72,
          "from_string",
          "return r.to_pdf(output_path)"
        ],
        [
          "/var/task/pdfkit/pdfkit.py",
          129,
          "to_pdf",
          "stderr=subprocess.PIPE)"
        ],
        [
          "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py",
          707,
          "__init__",
          "restore_signals, start_new_session)"
        ],
        [
          "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py",
          1326,
          "_execute_child",
          "raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)"
        ]
      ]
    }
```

**Code**

```
import boto3
import os,subprocess
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pdfkit
import codecs

LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT = os.environ.get('LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
CURR_BIN_DIR = os.path.join(LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT, 'bin')
LIB_DIR = os.path.join(LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT, 'lib')
BIN_DIR = '/tmp/bin'

def _init_bin(executable_name,bucket_name,region):
    start = time.clock()
    if not os.path.exists(BIN_DIR):
        print("Creating bin folder")
        os.makedirs(BIN_DIR)
    print("Copying binaries for "+executable_name+" in /tmp/bin")
    client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='xxxxxx',
                          aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxx',
                          region_name=region
                          )
    client.download_file(bucket_name,
                         'wkhtmltopdf', '/tmp/bin/wkhtmltopdf')
    newfile  = os.path.join(BIN_DIR, executable_name)
    print("Giving new binaries permissions for lambda")
    os.chmod(newfile, 777)
    elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
    print(executable_name+" ready in "+str(elapsed)+'s.')


def handler(event, context):
    bucket_name = event['bucketName']
    region = event['regionName']
    htmlFileName = event['htmlFileName']
    pdfName = htmlFileName.split(".")
    client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                          aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxx',
                          region_name=region
                          )
    client.download_file(bucket_name,
                         htmlFileName, '/tmp/' + htmlFileName)
    _init_bin('wkhtmltopdf',event['bucketName'],event['regionName'])
    f=codecs.open('/tmp/'+htmlFileName,'r','utf-8')
    document=BeautifulSoup(f.read()).get_text()
    path_wkthmltopdf ='/tmp/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
    c=pdfkit.from_string(document,False,configuration=config )
    #transfer = S3Transfer(client)
    #transfer.upload_file('/tmp/' + pdfName[0] + '.pdf', bucket_name, pdfName[0] + '.pdf')
```

**I have tried** to keep the wkhtmltopdf file in the zip package and then upload it but that returns the same error.

Is it possible with Aws lambda? I have already tried this out with EC2 instance and it works fine.

Comment: The Python library `wkhtmltopdf` is only a bridge/client to the `wkhtmltopdf` application which must be installed on the target server/system.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Are you able to get any answer?

Comment: you need to zip the lambda package after performing a chmod on all files. After this, it worked for me.